# Code output help please! WordPress> ACF > Relationship > Post Object

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, code

I am using ACF Relationship > Post Object on a custom post-type "family" to select another of the same post-type. My example usage is each post using this custom post-type = a person, the post object relationship is to select their Mom, and Dad. Each post (or person) will only have 2 post object relationships, 1. Mom and 2. Dad. My goal is to display the names as links of 5 generations, Mom, Dad, Grandfather, Grandmother, on a single post (person).

Example...

Post = Son > post object relationship 1.Mom and 2.Dad

Post = Daughter > post object relationship 1.Mom and 2.Dad

also posts could be...

Post = Mom > post object relationship 1.GrandmotherA and 2.GrandfatherB

Post = Dad > post object relationship 1.GrandmotherC and 2.GrandfatherD

I have tried tons of different code options, but nothing I have done shows the post object relationships past current post. What I'd like is the output the names like so...

[image]

Any help, tips, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.